# iOS App Update and User Defaults

Tags: ios, swift

I've developed a game and I released it to the App Store about 2 months ago (Supernatural Slayer). The game uses user defaults to store player data such as level, xp, gold, etc.

I want to update the game to include review requests which I programmed based on help from hacking with swift. (I also had to switch ad networks since chart boost suspended my account indefinitely for no reason...)

My question is that I seem to remember during development about 4-6 months ago that every time I added another variable to save and load from user defaults it would cause an existing game to crash and I would have to start from scratch by deleting and reloading the game onto my phone to erase user defaults. But now that I'm adding the reviewRequest variable it isn't causing the same error, I'm not sure if I'm not testing correctly and if once I update all of my players will lose their progress...

My code for the save and load functions is below, will this cause an error for existing users that update my app if I add the reviewRequest variable and the save and load lines for it? I've updated both my Mac OS and Xcode since it used to crash for me, so maybe this is why it is not an issue anymore?

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var reviewRequest = 0

func save() {
    defaults.set(reviewRequest, forKey: "Review Request")
    defaults.set(player.name, forKey: "PlayerName")
}

func load() {
    player.name = defaults.object(forKey: "PlayerName") as! String
    reviewRequest = defaults.integer(forKey: "Review Request")
}
```

Comment: You should maybe add a nil check. If you try and get a Default without having any data for the key, it will crash.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the following, thank you!

if reviewRequest == nil {
        reviewRequest = 0
    } else {reviewRequest = defaults.integer(forKey: "Review Request")}

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: That's much better, it's not the reviewRequest variable that would be nil it's the defaults object, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding a nil check to avoid trying to retrieve an empty key.

```
func load() {

    if defaults.object(forKey: "PlayerName") != nil {
      player.name = defaults.object(forKey: "PlayerName") as! String
    } else {
     //Default name or something similar
    }

   if defaults.object(forKey: "ReviewRequest") != nil {
        reviewRequest = defaults.integer(forKey: "Review Request")
        } else {
         reviewRequest = 0
        }
    }
```